# How to reset password using two different tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to reset password using same column name( email,password) in two different table

**Model code as shown below**

```
 public function resetpassword($user) {

        $data = array(
            'password' => ($this->input->post('newpassword'))
        );
       //$where = "id=5";
         $where = "id=$user";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->update('supplier_registration', $data);
    }
```

**Controller code as shown in below**

```
public function ResetPassword() {



        $emaill = $this->input->post('emaill');
        $otp = $this->input->post('otp');


      //$this->form_validation->set_rules('emaill', 'emaill', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]|matches[otp]');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('otp', 'otp', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword', 'newpassword', 'trim|required|max_length[15]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|matches[confirmpassword]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {


            if($this->session->userdata('otp') == "$otp" && $this->session->userdata('findemaill') == "$emaill" ) {
                $user = $this->session->userdata['idd'];
                $this->load->model('Login_model');
                $result['data'] = $this->Login_model->resetpassword($user,$emaill);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'successfull reset the password');
                $this->load->view('login');


           } 


        }

    }
```

Comment: Like you want to reset password in two tables having same column name using a single function?

Comment: yes i want to reset password using two different table column name are same

Comment: If those tables are 1to1 related, like with same ID value for each row, you can set after update trigger on table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to two parameters in `resetpassword($user,$email)` function in model.Then use `$this->db->set()` to set new password as below:

```
public function resetpassword($user,$email) {

            $new_password = $this->input->post('newpassword');
            $this->db->set('password',$new_password );
            $this->db->where('id',$user);
            $this->db->update('supplier_registration');
        }
```

Comment: But  i want to reset password using two different table column name are same example one table supplier_registration another table is customer_registration

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ResetPassword()
{
$emaill = $this->input->post('emaill');
    $otp = $this->input->post('otp');


  //$this->form_validation->set_rules('emaill', 'emaill', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]|matches[otp]');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('otp', 'otp', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword', 'newpassword', 'trim|required|max_length[15]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|matches[confirmpassword]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {


        if($this->session->userdata('otp') == "$otp" && $this->session->userdata('findemaill') == "$emaill" ) {
            $user = $this->session->userdata['idd'];
            $this->load->model('Login_model');
            $result['data'] = $this->Login_model->resetpassword($user,$emaill);
//as now you have got $user and $email, fire same query to another model having different table name
$result['data1'] = $this->Another_table_model->resetpassword($user,$emaill);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'successfull reset the password');
            $this->load->view('login');


       } 


    }
}
```

Check this code and let me know, you will call 2 methods of different model inside a same function

Comment: your code is working but one problem occuring in two table same id means it will reset in two table password

Comment: you can keep conditions to that or do you have any than I can modify it